# My loop always skip the first index

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

Every time I creat a loop function, it's common to have problem with the first one:

For example:

```
dfd = quandl.get("FRED/DEXBZUS")
dfe = quandl.get("ECB/EURBRL")


df = [dfd, dfe]
dps = []

for i in df:
```

I just get the second dataframe values.

Using this:

```
dfd = quandl.get("FRED/DEXBZUS")


df = [dfd]
dps = []

for i in df:
```

I got this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

And if I use this (repeting the first one):

```
dfd = quandl.get("FRED/DEXBZUS")
dfe = quandl.get("ECB/EURBRL")


df = [dfd, dfd, dfe]
dps = []

for i in df:
```

I get both dataframes correcly

```
Examples :

import quandl
import pandas as pd
#import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dfd = quandl.get("FRED/DEXBZUS")
dfe = quandl.get("ECB/EURBRL")


df = [dfd, dfe]
dps = []

for i in df:
    df1 = i.reset_index()
    results = pd.DataFrame(df1)
    results = results.rename(columns={'Date': 'ds','Value': 'y'})
    dps = pd.DataFrame(dps.append(results))
    print(dps)


Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
             ds       y
0    2008-01-02  2.6010
1    2008-01-03  2.5979
2    2008-01-04  2.5709
3    2008-01-07  2.6027
4    2008-01-08  2.5796
```

## UPDATE

As Bruno suggested, it is related to this function:

```
dps = pd.DataFrame(dps.append(results))
```

How to append all the dataset into a one data frame ?

Comment: What are you doing inside the loop? how are you getting/printing the results?

Comment: Python doesn't skip values by itself so the problem (whatever it is) is in your code - obviously in some part you didn't post (the for loop's body being an obvious suspect).

Comment: I posted an example

Comment: what do you expect `dps = pd.DataFrame(dps.append(results))` to do exactly ? Hint 1: `list.append()` returns `None`. Hint 2: after the first execution of this line, `dps` isn't a `list` anymore.

Comment: I just want to gather all the dataset into a one dataframe after doing some manipulation

Comment: Remember to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
#this will print every element in df
for i in df:
    print i
```

Also,

```
for dfIndex, i in enumerate(df):
    print i
    print dfIndex #this will print the index of i in df
```

Note that indexes start at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

`result=Pd.DataFrame(df1)`    If you create dataframe like this and don't give columns, then by default first it will take 1st row as column and later you are renaming columns what default created.
So please create `pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=[column_list])`.
First row will not skip.